# Dimensions of matrices inside a list() object

Tags: r, list

This is a very basic question but unfortunately I cannot find a direct answer, and I am not really used to work with list objects.

I have a list object, `MATRICES_list`, composed by say 100 matrices of different dimensions. I need to know the dimension of each of this matrices. Is there a way for doing so without using a loop?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is even easier, you can use this:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(MATRICES_list, dim))
```